# How to create custom selector with TypeScript which both Nodelist and Element types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create a custom find selector instead of using pure javascript querySelector tags. I extended Element type with my custom function addClass(). But querySelectorAll returns Nodelistof Element, whereas querySelector returns Element. So TypeScript gives error as result of find can be Nodelistof Element or Element. I want to be able to do use my find function on both single or multiple element selection. And I also want to use my custom functions e.g. addClass or forEach (which nodelist of element method).

```
function find(selector: string) 
    {
       let elements = document.body.querySelectorAll(selector);
       if (elements.length === 1) return elements[0] as Element;
       else return elements;
    }

    interface Element 
    {
        addClass(className: string): Element;
    }

   Element.prototype.addClass = function (className) 
    {
       this.classList.add(className);
       return this;
    }
```

My solution was adding forEach method to Element interface and extending Nodelist interface with my custom Element interface. But I think this may not be best practice for TypeScript. By this way, I able to add forEach for single Element and addClass method to Nodelist Element.

```
 interface Element 
        {
            addClass(className: string): Element;
            forEach(callback: Function): any;
        }
    
    interface NodeList extends Element {}
    
    Element.prototype.forEach = function (myFunction: Function) 
    {
      myFunction(this);
    }
```

I also have find method on my Element interface

```
interface Element 
    {
        addClass(className: string): Element;
        forEach(callback: Function): any;
        find(selector: string): NodeList | Element;
    }

Element.prototype.find = function (selector) 
{
  let elements = document.body.querySelectorAll(selector);
  if (elements.length === 1) return elements[0] as Element;
  else return elements;
}
```

This works, but is there better approach to this problem in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

**util.ts** — [TS Playground test](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogNhAthAdsGAPYqAmEdQC8sCyaUAZFAN4BQUUAxnAIYDObAgjjgFxShIAewBmTVh244ANLQC%20tWiICuKRsACWQlOPZceACmAALDW37wkqYNKgA6B8CEBrVOahtgAJw0oA5gDaALoAlDT0AqZsdsx6ADJmwHYshg52Tq4obCHyiipqmtpQAI7KEF4gBmwQCOpCXvyePv4h-AByQngJngDyIgA8lmToWLj4AHzhDF4QwMpeOjhCjMrDdqXlIADKNRB1XpxwcFW7%20zkKSqrqWjobFZxeXiyV1bVODR7evn6tJFZomGwKDwOGCUygMzmCygDyeIDsIi8QkQBjuL1O7xC50UBiG1jsYCRTkE0HYf2GgLGOBCMQk%20gIxFikh4iggGDA9WA4LRsgYaNhz1kCiAA)

```js
type ElementExtended = Element & {
  classAdd: typeof classAdd,
}

function classAdd(this: Element, ...tokens: string[]) {
  this.classList.add(...tokens)
}

function query(selector: string): NodeListOf<ElementExtended> {
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector)
}

function queryArray(selector: string): ElementExtended[] {
  return Array.from(query(selector))
}

(Element.prototype as ElementExtended).classAdd = classAdd

export {
  query,
  queryArray,
}
```

**test.js**

```js
import { query } from './util'

query('foo')[0]?.classAdd('bar')
```

Comment: Bu I want to be able to addClass to nodelist and element without specifying array index. I mean I want to use it like this query('foo').classAdd('bar')

Comment: `(NodeList.prototype as ...).classAdd = ...`